# Video tile in photo library

Tags: ios, swift

So I have been searching over the internet for a way to accomplish the goal of having a video tile. My current implementation accomplishes the goal of only showing videos but I have to go into the camera roll first to see them. All I want to is have a title or album that just says videos so that when you go in there the videos are there as well as showing the number of videos not camera roll which has the number of all things present and then when you go in there you see the video. I have changed my imagepickerController source type as photoLibrary and I have already changed the mediaTypes to properly account for videos. So changing that one line isn't the answer for those people that might add it as an answer.

[image]

I have added the code for the imagepickercontroller

```
import Foundation
import Eureka
import MobileCoreServices

/// Selector Controller used to pick an video
open class ImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController, TypedRowControllerType, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    /// The row that pushed or presented this controller
    public var row: RowOf<URL>!
    //setting navigation controller delegate

    /// A closure to be called when the controller disappears.
    public var onDismissCallback : ((UIViewController) -> ())?

    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
        allowsEditing = (row as? _VideoRow)?.allowEditor ?? false
        mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String, kUTTypeVideo as String]
    }
    public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        guard let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL else {
            return
        }

        (row as? _VideoRow)?.videoURL = videoURL
        (row as? _VideoRow)?.value = videoURL
        onDismissCallback?(self)
    }

    open func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
        onDismissCallback?(self)
    }

    public func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        viewController.navigationItem.title = "Videos"
    }

}
```

Is there anything wrong or can anyone point me in the direction of where I would go to show me how to create a video tile or album or show me an example. I ultimately want something like this

[image]

Where there is only a video album though

Answer (score 0):

Videos, like any other media type, isn't an album so you can't just request it as one from `UIImagePickerController`. In fact, `UIImagePickerController` is probably not going to cut it for your use case since it's very restrictive in its functionality.

Basically, just like on a macOS desktop, there isn't a single folder with just your videos in it. You have to query for it. In iOS, you can accomplish that by calling `fetchAssetsWithMediaType:options:` on `PHAsset` (setting the media type to `.video` of course). You can narrow down your results using predicates (`NSPredicate`) or sort it using sort descriptors (`NSSortDescriptor`), both set on `PHFetchOptions`. You can wrap the whole thing in a data source that will also give you your other albums like Camera Roll or whatever else you need. This would be custom code using `PHAsset*` functions to return only the collections/assets you're interested in.

Once you have your data source, you can build your UI with it. You can accomplish the UI you want with a simple `UITableView` and some custom cells but now you'll also be responsible for fetching the album art, titles, counts, etc., for each album. You can also delegate that logic to your data source so that your UI just reads from it. There's a lot of asynchronous behavior built in to the `PHAsset*` classes so you'll need to make sure to handle that correctly. Then you need to account for remote iCloud content, which isn't included by default so you'll need to set `includeAssetSourceTypes` to a proper value on `PHFetchOptions`.

All of this is a sizable amount of work. Especially if you expected there to be a convenience method or a boolean on `UIImagePickerController` that would give you what you want. I'm not aware of one so the long way is the only way I can think of. However, there's a ton of image pickers out there and a lot of them come with open licenses. I recommend you Google a few and see if one gives you what you need. If not, you can always DIY it.